# Sending a Mathematica Snippet to be evaulated by Mathematica Online?

Tags: mathematica-online

Is there a way to take an arbitrary Mathematica snippet (say from Emacs) and to have it be evaluated by Mathematica Online (i.e., start a new notebook in a browser and evaluate the snippet)?

Comment: You can write an `APIFunction` then ping that. It might not be cheap though as the Wolfram Cloud is almost prohibitively expensive for casual use.

Comment: I believe you're looking for `wolframscript` (unless you want to continue working in the notebook session). Try something like `wolframscript -cloud -code 'StringReverse["Hello"]'` - that will evaluate in the cloud on your account. It also doesn't appear to use Cloud Credits.

Comment: By the way, if you're writing an emacs package to evaluate Mathematica snippets, ping me when you're done! There are a handful of syntax highlighters but no `org-babel` integration that I know of, for instance.